# container with position relative shrinkwraps when images are floated

Tags: position, css-position

I have a website I am creating for a school project. I am very new to html and css. I have created div containers for the different sections of my pages. On my index page, I have 5 containers including the header and footer.

The containers are working everywhere except in 1 location where I am floating images. For some reason, the box is shrink-wrapping under the 3 images. I thought by placing a position:relative in the .container css rule, it would behave like it is with paragraphs and other elements. I would like that container to surround the pictures just like it is with the other boxes on the index page.

Here is the html for that specific container that is not working:

```
 <div class="container">
        <article>
            <h2>Meet the Staff:</h2>
                <div class="gallery">
                    <figure class="staff"><img src="images/mary.jpg" alt="mary the librarian" />
                        <figcaption>Mary the Librarian</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div class="gallery">
                    <figure class="staff"><img src="images/ruth.jpg" alt="mary the librarian" />
                        <figcaption>Ruth the Assistant</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div class="gallery">
                    <figure class="staff"><img src="images/esther.jpg" alt="mary the librarian" />
                        <figcaption>Esther the Research Librarian</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                 </div>
        </article>
      </div>
```

And here is the css:

```
.container {
width: 1000px;
height: auto;
margin: auto;
margin-bottom: 25px;
padding: 0 20px;
position: relative;
background: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #b5b2ab;
```

}

```
figure img {
border: 1px solid #666;
background-color: #fff;
padding: 4px;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
```

}

```
figcaption {
font: Arial, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
margin: 10px 0 0 0;
```

}

```
figure {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 240px;
margin: 0 25px 25px 25px;
```

}

Here is the so you can see what is happening: http://www.ta5zc.com/

Thanks for any help you can provide. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassing, but I figured it out. The container is acting just like it is supposed to. There was no elements below the images, so there was nothing to stay in place. Therefore, when I floated the images, the box moved up the page like it was supposed to. Like I said, I'm new at this ;-)